# Crontab @reboot not executed

Tags: javascript, linux, cron, raspberry-pi

Hy,

I am having some troubles setting up my cronjob on my raspberry pi.
I am sure that my code runs fine, but when i try to run my cronjob it does nothing.

i have used the following command to open the crontab:

```
sudo crontab -e
```

then I have added the following line of code to it:

```
@reboot sleep 10 | node /PATH/index.js &
```

I have also tried to do this:

```
@reboot sleep 10 && node /PATH/index.js &
```

Then I save the file and exit the file.
Then I reboot the file..
When the raspberry pi is back on i do the following command to see if the cronjob is being executed:

But the cronjob isnt being executed.

```
grep cron /var/log/syslog
```

I get the folowing:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nXHuK.png)

As you can see it says that it is running the @reboot cronjobs but it is not working at the moment.
My friend has 100% the same code and did the same thing as i did and it works on his raspberry pi but not on mine....

Thanks

Comment: My guess : Check the path of the `sleep` command with `where sleep` and use it in the crontab command. With `|` like with `&&`, if the cron daemon fails to find the sleep command it will not execute the node part. You may also need to explicitly invoke the shell for your command as your cron daemon will probably not be able to interpret `&&`, something like `/bin/bash -c "/bin/sleep 10 && node ..."`

Comment: @Zilog80 thanks for the reply! I dont think that it is a problem with the sleep. When i excecute yhis command in the terminal, the program starts after the 10 seconds. So I think its fine...

Comment: Have you tried with `/bin/bash -c "<your command>"` ?

Comment: I have just tried this but it still doesnt work :/ ...

Comment: Did you get a local mail about the cron job ? Your node.js is the usual path (/usr/bin/node) ? Check also if you have a _stuck_ node process after reboot  with `ps`.

Comment: No i havent, but in my code i write some logs to a file on my raspberry pi and this also doesnt work...

Answer (score 0):

I know this an old thread; but what works for me is to separate the two commands with a ";". In the example of OP, I would have written it as:

```
@reboot sleep 10 ; node /PATH/index.js
```